# How to store a serialized array with node mysql driver

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, serialization

I'm writing a game where users are able to save and load created "maps" consisting of points that define the vertices of a top-down map (think 1993 Doom WADs).

I take a list of vertices (nodes) and serialize them.

```
let nodes = [{'x': 1, 'y': 1}, {'x': 5, 'y': 4}, ...];
const data = JSON.stringify(nodes);
```

Then insert them into a table

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO mapnodes VALUES (?)', [data], (error, results, fields) => {
    ...
});
```

The problem is that the escaping that the mysql driver does turns the serialized string into an array when I really want to insert a single string value.

This is what the mysql driver sees:

```
"INSERT INTO mapnodes VALUES ('[object Object],[object Object], ...')"
```

My questions are 1) Is this a bad database schema? Should I be storing the nodes differently?
and <strike>2) How can I both escape the string and keep it a single string value?</strike>

EDIT:
Actually, a POST request is what changes the string to a JSON object, but the question remains - Is this the recommended way to store potentially thousands of coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL [the JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), not string data type. Thus you'll simplify your code and optimize it reducing data type transformations, get additional data object validation at database engine level, make your datatable independent from future JSON object structure modification.